# How to get the the createdAt timestamp without 'GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, replit

I have searched everywhere for this but I haven't got the right answer. I just want to set it without the CUT time.

```
{name: "Registered:", value: `${user.createdAt}`},
    
{name: "Joined:", value: `${message.guild.joinedAt}`}
```

It currently shows up like this:
[click here to see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEoyK.png)

Is there any way to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the properties are JS [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instances, you can use one of these functions to do it:

```js
function formatDateV1 (date) {
  return date.toLocaleString(undefined, {dateStyle: 'medium', timeStyle: 'medium', hour12: false});
}

function formatDateV2 (date) {
  return `${date.toDateString()} ${date.toTimeString().slice(0, 8)}`;
}

const date = new Date();
const user = {createdAt: date};
const message = {guild: {joinedAt: date}};

const registerV1 = {name: "Registered:", value: formatDateV1(user.createdAt)};
console.log('registerV1', registerV1);

const joinV1 = {name: "Joined:", value: formatDateV1(message.guild.joinedAt)};
console.log('joinV1', joinV1);

const registerV2 = {name: "Registered:", value: formatDateV2(user.createdAt)}
console.log('registerV2', registerV2);

const joinV2 = {name: "Joined:", value: formatDateV2(message.guild.joinedAt)}
console.log('joinV2', joinV2);
```